# Unsupported URL Error after successful call

Tags: ios, dispatch-async

I am confused with why the error block is calling even if the images are downloaded and displayed successfully. The error I get in log is,

> Error = Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo=0x7fe7840d8000 {NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe781d5b5e0 "unsupported URL", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=, NSErrorFailingURLKey=, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}

Even I get this error, I can get the image, parse it and display it in the app. Where am I wrong in this code,

```
@try{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *res, NSData *data, NSError *error){
 UIImage *thumbImage = nil;
 if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){
    NSLog(@"image was downloaded.");
    thumbImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
 }
 else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil){
    NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
    [loaderView removeFromSuperview];
 }
 else if (error != nil){
    NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
    [loaderView removeFromSuperview];
 }
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    imageViewtoApply.image = thumbImage;
    [webServiceDelegate imageDownloadFinished];
    [loaderView removeFromSuperview];
    });
   }];
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the http status code, it probably is an error code.

Cast the response to `NSHTTPURLResponse` and examine the `statusCode` property.

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *URLResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)res;
NSLog(@"http status code: res.statusCode", %i);
```

Comment: The status code is '0'. If its 0 how the images can be downloaded and displayed?

Comment: Really? See [Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), 0 is not one of them. You can always use [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com) to see the request and response.